# 2016 - Maintaining our '100%' answer rate and trending our answer rank to 1st

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, fun, statistics

At time of writing (June 28th, 2016) we have:

- [166 questions with no upvoted or accepted answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest)
- [146 questions with no answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers)
- a [99%ish answer rate, which puts us at 16th overall](http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) on the network

I'd like to track this with the goal of getting the answer rate up to 100% (with rounding, at least), and our rank site-wide at 1st for answering, and as such will occasionally update below with updated stats.  Feel free to do this as well.

Comment: Is 100% answer rate a realistic or desirable goal? Answering as many as possible is obviously good, but sometimes questions legitimately don't have answers yet because they're challenging, interesting questions about routes or situations few people have taken yet - better to leave these for adventurous souls to answer well when possible than fill them with fluff or close them spuriously, surely? If we had the most answered questions of *any* site, I'd worry our pool of questions was too easy

Comment: (drawing attention to unanswered questions is obviously a good thing and tracking it like this is a good idea, I'm just worried people might get obsessive treating the stats as an end itself not a means to an end, pushing the stats at the expense of giving interesting questions good answers)

Comment: @user568458 you're not the first to wonder, and we [did the same thing last year](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3367/trending-our-answer-rate-to-100-and-our-answer-rank-to-1st) with some success. We didn't get to zero, but definitely got a lot of it under control :)

Comment: Okay, great. Just hope this isn't what's been driving the recent trend of spurious close-voting...

Comment: @user568458 this has only been active a few hours, with 14 views, so I'd hope not either :)

Comment: Regarding the desire to be first... five the sites currently ranked higher than Travel are Language sites (Spanish, Russian, German, French, Chinese).  I suppose language sites might be easier to provide conclusive answers (either something is part of a language, which can often be verified, or it isn't), whereas Travel is much more open-ended about tons of types of travel situations, in various locations, which could be obscure spots.  I speculate those sites may often have more completion just by nature of the topics.

Comment: Would it be worth excluding newer questions from the statistics? For example only accounting for questions asked more than 24 hours ago would probably translate in much stable statistics as a question just asked is obviously unanswered and an answer just posted is obviously not yet voted on. A question that has had no answer (or no voted on answer) within 24 hours, however, should be rare given the pace of the site.

Comment: @MatthieuM. probably, but it's a more more complicated to work out each time, and they'll get cleared up daily (well, most of them).

Comment: @pnuts : For what purpose?  If you place a mediocre answer, then the question is no longer as easily identified as not having any quality answers, which means some people are less likely to find the question (if they are searching for questions without quality answers, by looking for unanswered questions).  And getting a higher completion rate by settling on mediocrity is, well, an uninspiring strategy (at least, when phrased the way I just did).

Comment: @pnuts In general, I'd want whatever gives me the best answers.  In hindsight.  So, silence is not preferred, except if it actually leads to better answers.  By the way, that "comment" answer of yours was pretty good.  Maybe not solidly conclusive, but any three-and-a-half-screen comment written as well as that is much better than simply "feeble".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Update answer below with the following:

- [date of update](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current%20time%20utc) **(Date)**
- [# questions with no upvoted or accepted answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest) **(NoVotes)**
- [# questions with no answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers) **(NoAnswers)**
- [% answer rate](http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) on the network **(%Answered)**
- [rank for answer rate](http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) on the network **(Rank)**

```
+----------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| Date                 | NoVotes | NoAnswers | %Answered | Rank   |
+----------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| December 21st, 2016  |   76    |   70      |100%       |  9th   |
| December 20th, 2016  |   80    |   75      |100%       | 10th   |
| December 15th, 2016  |   78    |   76      |100%       |  9th   |
| November 28th, 2016  |   54    |   52      |100%       |  6th   |
| November 26th, 2016  |   52    |   50      |100%       |  5th   |
| November 25th, 2016  |   56    |   50      |100%       |  5th   |
| November 24th, 2016  |   63    |   59      |100%       |  8th   |
| November 23rd, 2016  |   64    |   61      |100%       |  7th   |
| November 22th, 2016  |   66    |   61      |100%       |  8th   |
| November 15th, 2016  |   61 ↓  |   56 ↓    |100%       |  7th↑  |
| November 14th, 2016  |   66 ↑  |   61 ↑    |100%       |  8th↓  |
| November 10th, 2016  |   64 ↓  |   59 ↓    |100%       |  6th↑  |
| November 9th, 2016   |   67 ↓  |   64      |100%       |  9th↓  |
| November 6th, 2016   |   70 ↓  |   64 ↓    |100%       |  7th↑  |
| November 5th, 2016   |   73 ↓  |   67 ↓    |100%       |  8th↑  |
| November 4th, 2016   |   77 ↓  |   70 ↓    |100%       |  9th   |
| November 3rd, 2016   |   81 ↓  |   75 ↓    |100%       |  9th   |
| November 2nd, 2016   |   83 ↓  |   78 ↓    |100%       |  9th↑  |
| November 1st, 2016   |   97 ↓  |   89 ↓    |100%       | 10th↓  |
| October 31st, 2016   |   99 ↑  |   94 ↑    |100%       |  9th↑  |
| October 27th, 2016   |   97 ↑  |   91 ↑    |100%       | 10th   |
| October 24th, 2016   |   92 ↑  |   87 ↑    |100%       | 10th   |
| October 23rd, 2016   |   91 ↓  |   85 ↓    |100% ↑     | 10th   |
| October 22nd, 2016   |  100 ↓  |   95 ↓    | 99%       | 10th   |
| October 18th, 2016   |  112 ↑  |  107 ↑    | 99%       | 10th   |
| October 17th, 2016   |  105 ↓  |   99 ↓    | 99%       | 10th   |
| October 16th, 2016   |  116 ↓  |  108 ↓    | 99%       | 10th ↑ |
| October 15th, 2016   |  123 ↓  |  113 ↓    | 99%       | 11th   |
| October 11th, 2016   |  132 ↑  |  117 ↑    | 99%       | 11th   |
| October 10th, 2016   |  128 ↓  |  115 ↓    | 99%       | 11th   | 
| October 9th, 2016    |  131 ↓  |  118 ↓    | 99%       | 11th ↑ | 
| October 8th, 2016    |  138 ↓  |  123 ↓    | 99%       | 13th   | 
| October 7th, 2016    |  140 ↓  |  125 ↓    | 99%       | 13th   |
| October 6th, 2016    |  143 ↓  |  126 ↓    | 99%       | 13th   |
| October 5th, 2016    |  145 ↓  |  129 ↓    | 99%       | 13th ↑ |
| October 3rd, 2016    |  148    |  131 ↓    | 99%       | 14th ↓ |
| October 2nd, 2016    |  148 ↓  |  135 ↓    | 99%       | 13th ↑ |
| October 1st, 2016    |  151    |  136 ↓    | 99%       | 15th   |
| September 29th, 2016 |  151 ↓  |  137 ↓    | 99%       | 15th   |
| September 27th, 2016 |  158 ↓  |  145 ↓    | 99%       | 15th   |
| September 24th, 2016 |  162 ↓  |  146 ↓    | 99%       | 15th ↓ |
| September 19th, 2016 |  163 ↓  |  153 ↓    | 99%       | 13th ↑ |
| September 18th, 2016 |  171 ↓  |  157 ↑    | 99%       | 14th   |
| September 17th, 2016 |  181 ↓  |  155 ↓    | 99%       | 14th   |
| September 16th, 2016 |  183    |  159 ↓    | 99%       | 14th   |
| September 14th, 2016 |  183 ↑  |  160 ↓    | 99%       | 14th   | 
| September 10th, 2016 |  178 ↓  |  161 ↓    | 99%       | 14th   |  
| September 8th, 2016  |  181 ↓  |  163 ↓    | 99%       | 14th ↑ |    
| September 4th, 2016  |  183 ↑  |  168 ↑    | 99%       | 15th ↑ |  
| July 19th, 2016      |  157 ↓  |  142 ↓    | 99%       | 16th ↓ | 
| July 17th, 2016      |  164 ↑  |  149 ↑    | 99%       | 15th   |
| July 15th, 2016      |  156 ↓  |  139 ↓    | 99%       | 15th ↑ |
| July 14th, 2016      |  165 ↑  |  144 ↑    | 99%       | 16th ↓ |
| July 11th, 2016      |  159 ↓  |  139      | 99%       | 15th ↓ |
| July 9th, 2016       |  160 ↑  |  139 ↑    | 99%       | 14th   |
| July 8th, 2016       |  152 ↑  |  132      | 99%       | 14th   | 
| July 7th, 2016       |  150 ↓  |  132 ↓    | 99%       | 14th   | 
| July 6th, 2016       |  156 ↑  |  138 ↑    | 99%       | 14th ↑ |
| July 5th, 2016       |  150 ↓  |  131 ↓    | 99%       | 15th   |
| July 4th, 2016       |  154 ↓  |  136 ↓    | 99%       | 15th   | 
| July 3rd, 2016       |  157 ↑  |  142 ↑    | 99%       | 15th   | 
| July 2nd, 2016       |  156 ↑  |  139 ↑    | 99%       | 15th   | 
| July 1st, 2016       |  152 ↓  |  133 ↓    | 99%       | 15th   | 
| June 30th, 2016      |  163 ↑  |  138 ↓    | 99%       | 15th   | 
| June 29th, 2016      |  159 ↓  |  139 ↓    | 99%       | 15th ↑ | 
| June 28th, 2016      |  166    |  146      | 99%       | 16th   | 
+----------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+--------+
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, I believe congratulations are in order:

[image: 100 %!]

Comment: Still not ranked #1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not encouraging you to go and close all the unanswered questions, but probably this is also something you could do with the questions which weren't answered for the *good* reason (not any questions should be answered there after all). The closed unanswered questions are removed from "unanswered" tab.

I mean, you shouldn't answer any question just because it lacks an answer.

Comment: We always encourage "researching" before answer in TSE. We always did that and we learn a lot during that. We never "answer" just to "answer". Not how things go here.

Comment: @Heidel I didn't imply that.

Comment: This would be throwing out the baby with the bathwater. You'd close good questions, to which somebody might know the answer some day, just to get a statistic closer to 100%. Not very user friendly.